# Why does the Try-Catch block affect a variable in an enclosing scope?

Tags: c++, try-catch

Why does the outer `temp` become empty after catching first exception?

```
#include <iostream>
int main()
{
    std::string temp("exception");
    int value;
    while(std::cin>> value && value != 0)
    {
         try{
              if(value > 9) throw temp;
              else std::cout << value << "\n";
            }
         catch(std::string temp)
         {
              std::cout << temp << "\n";
         }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
1
2
11
13
```

Output:

```
1
2
exception
// Printing Empty string
```

Expected Output:

```
1
2
exception
exception
```

I compile my code with g++ 7.3.0.

Comment: Seems to work fine and as expected with `clang 7`. Reproducible with `gcc 8`, declaring `temp` as `const std::string temp("exception");` seems to fix this.

Comment: I can reproduce it with "gcc (GCC) 7.4.0", cygwin version

Comment: It seems issue relating to flushing your output .. I will give it a try on GCC and post an answer for you

Comment: @lubgr thanks it worked.

Comment: I can also reproduce on GCC 8.3, MSYS2 version.

Comment: Fails with g++-6.5 as well, but works as intended with g++-5.5. Did you file a bug at https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/?

Comment: @chtz No, i did not.

Comment: The issue had been reported some years ago: https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57533

Answer (score 40, accepted):

This appears to be a bug in GCC's implementation of copy elision. The C++ standard says the following:

> **[class.copy.elision]** (emphasis mine)
>
> This elision of copy/move operations, called copy elision, is
>   permitted in the following circumstances (which may be combined to
>   eliminate multiple copies):
>
> - in a throw-expression, when the operand is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause
>     parameter) **whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the
>     innermost enclosing try-block (if there is one)**, the copy/move
>     operation from the operand to the exception object can be omitted by
>     constructing the automatic object directly into the exception object
>
> In the following copy-initialization contexts, a move operation might
>   be used instead of a copy operation:
>
> - if the operand of a throw-expression is the name of a non-volatile automatic object (other than a function or catch-clause parameter)
>     **whose scope does not extend beyond the end of the innermost enclosing try-block (if there is one)**,

This is a family of optimizations that allows the copy initialization of an exception object to be either avoided or done as efficiently as possible. Now, a common implementation of `std::string` move construction is to leave the source string empty. This appears to be exactly what happens to your code. The `temp` in the outer scope is moved from (and left empty).

But that is not the intended behavior. The scope of the `temp` you throw *exceeds* (by far) the try block it's thrown in. So GCC has no business applying copy elision to it.

A possible workaround is to place the declaration of `temp` inside the `while` loop. This initialized a new `std::string` object every iteration, so even if `GCC` moves from it, it won't be noticeable.

Another workaround was mentioned in the comments and is to make the outer `temp` a const object. This will force a copy (since a move operation requires a non-const source object).

Answer (score -11):

I am not sure if it is a bug or not as mentioned in another answer but somehow catch block is changing / omitting the content of temp after handling the exception once. Below code resolves this issue. Make the `temp` a `const` to solve this.

```
#include <iostream>
    int main()
    {
        const std::string temp("exception");
        int value;
        while(std::cin>> value && value != 0)
        {
             try{
                  if(value > 9) throw temp;
                  else std::cout << value << "\n";
                }
             catch(std::string temp){
                  std::cerr << temp << "\n";
                  }
        }

        return 0;
    }
```

Comment: An hour before you wrote your answer, this solution was mentioned both in a comment and in the answer by @StoryTeller.

Comment: Believe it or not, I didn't really see those comments and had started playing with this code and as soon as it worked I posted my answer. Taking it as a lesson to read all the comments before posting my answers. Thanks for the down votes.