# Does const allow for (theoretical) optimization here?

Tags: c++, constants, language-lawyer, compiler-optimization

Consider this snippet:

```
void foo(const int&);

int bar();

int test1()
{
    int x = bar();
    int y = x;
    foo(x);
    return x - y;
}

int test2()
{
    const int x = bar();
    const int y = x;
    foo(x);
    return x - y;
}
```

In my understanding of the standard, neither `x` nor `y` are allowed to be changed by `foo` in `test2`, whereas they could be changed by `foo` in `test1` (with e.g. a `const_cast` to remove `const` from the `const int&` because the referenced objects aren't actually const in `test1`).

Now, [neither gcc nor clang nor MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/eI0bXA) seem to optimize `test2` to `foo(bar()); return 0;`, and I can understand that they do not want to waste optimization passes on an optimization that only rarely applies in practice.

But am I at least correct in my understanding of this situation, or am I missing some legal way for `x` to be modified in `test2`?

Comment: The compiler cannot really optimize based on `const`, in general, since the language has, for example; `const_cast` and `mutable`.

Comment: @JesperJuhl: `x` is const, so it cannot be modified. It is UB to remove `const` with `const_cast` and modify it.

Comment: @geza Yes. In this example it is obvious. But in many cases the compiler cannot know if the original object is const or not.

Comment: @JesperJuhl That's like saying that the compiler cannot really optimise based on types, since the language has incomplete types.

Comment: @eerorika Ok, then show me a modern compiler where the optimizer actually uses `const` to its advantage.

Comment: @JesperJuhl There's [this](https://godbolt.org/z/xMuMVB) example from another SO comment from Max earlier. Besides, modern compilers failing to use constness to their advantage wouldn't necessarily prove that it couldn't be used. It can potentially only show that it isn't used. I do wish we had standard `__attribute__((const))` though; that would be even more useful than const objects.

Comment: @eerorika Ok. Compilers may have gotten smarter since I last looked at that.

Comment: @JesperJuhl I don't think that's very new. Just basic constant folding optimisation. It's easy because the expression is compile time constant. What the example in question is about though is run-time constness, which is not taken advantage of. Presumably because it is too expensive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The standard says in [[dcl.type.cv]](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4):

> Except that any class member declared `mutable` […] can be modified, any attempt to modify […] a const object […] during its lifetime […] results in undefined behavior.

It is also not possible to make this defined by ending the lifetime of the object prematurely, according to [[basic.life]](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.life#10):

> Creating a new object within the storage that a const complete object with […] automatic storage duration occupies, or within the storage that such a const object used to occupy before its lifetime ended, results in undefined behavior.

This means that the optimization of `x - y` to zero is valid because any attempt to modify `x` in `foo` would result in undefined behavior.

The interesting question is if there is a reason for not performing this optimization in existing compilers.  Considering that the const object definition is local to `test2` and the fact is used within the same function, usual exceptions such as support for symbol interposition do not apply here.